# Difference between tf.add() and tensorflow.keras.layers.Add()

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have implemented a Deep Learning model (FCN-8s) in tensorflow and initially used `tf.add(x,y)` to perform the tensor addition. However, when plotting the architecture, the addition layers seem to be disconected from the rest [image: (see architecture)], but in the summary it appears that the result of this operation is effectively passed to the next layer [image: (see summary)]
When using `tensorflow.keras.layers.Add` or `tensorflow.keras.layers.add`, then the addition layers are correclty connected to the rest of the network.

My question is pretty simple:

- Is there any difference between using `tf.add()` and `tensorflow.keras.layers.Add()`.
- Besides, is there any difference between `tensorflow.keras.layers.Add()` and `tensorflow.keras.layers.add()`? I have seen some code using Add with upper and other with lowercase.

Comment: Just want to add that I run the same code with each of the options and the results are very similar. val_loss_tf_add=0.235 and val_loss_Add()=0.232. I assume that there is no difference between the methods, but I still don't know why the addition is not properly connected to the rest of the layers with the first option.

Comment: `tf.add()` is use to add tensors and `tf.keras.layers.Add()` / `add()`  is use to add two layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.add` and `tensorflow.keras.layers.Add` have different implementation methods.

In **gen_math_ops.py** (a file generated by the system)

tf.add

```
_result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
            _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "Add", name, tld.op_callbacks,
            x, y)
```

tensorflow.keras.layers.Add

```
_result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
        _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "AddV2", name,
        tld.op_callbacks, x, y)
```

Their corresponding C source code

```
REGISTER_OP("Add")
    .Input("x: T")
    .Input("y: T")
    .Output("z: T")
    .Attr(
        "T: {bfloat16, half, float, double, uint8, int8, int16, int32, int64, "
        "complex64, complex128, string}")
    .SetShapeFn(shape_inference::BroadcastBinaryOpShapeFn);

// TODO(rmlarsen): Add a Python wrapper that swiches non-string instances to
// use AddV2 (b/68646025).
REGISTER_OP("AddV2")
    .Input("x: T")
    .Input("y: T")
    .Output("z: T")
    .Attr(
        "T: {bfloat16, half, float, double, uint8, int8, int16, int32, int64, "
        "complex64, complex128}")
    .SetShapeFn(shape_inference::BroadcastBinaryOpShapeFn)
    .SetIsAggregate()
    .SetIsCommutative();
```

That is to say, tf.add is 'Add' but tensorflow.keras.layers.Add is 'AddV2'

---

`tensorflow.keras.layers.Add` and `tensorflow.keras.layers.add` are the same. `tensorflow.keras.layers.add` is just functional interface of `tensorflow.keras.layers.Add`

---

I cant reproduce the addition layers is disconected from the rest when using tf.add

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When I mean "disconnected" I meant that in the architecture the tf.add() layer is only connected to one of the inputs. For example, tf.add_12 has "max_pool4_nb_classes" and "convtransp_1" as inputs, but in the architecture plot it is only connected to "max_pool4_nb_classes". When I changed it to tf.keras.layers.Add(), then it was connected to both inputs in the architecture plot.

Comment: Finally, even though they have different implementations (tf.add() vs tf.keras.layers.Add()), can one use them indistinctively when defining a model? Thanks!

Comment: @pe basically, both of them return x + y element-wise.

Comment: Almost the same

Comment: I know your "disconnected" means. But I follow this repo:https://github.com/dmitryako/keras_fcn_8s/blob/master/dk2_vgg16fcn8s_model.py, the tf.add and the layers.add give me same architecture plot

Comment: I put the code for my implementation in a colab. Could you have a quick look at it? That would help me massively to understand why my layers are disconnected: 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19df08BfEr3WRTMofe40q4J-qJBkQ81Sk?usp=sharing